# Implementing of container with map inside

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdmap

i want to realize container with map inside and implement operations of insert key/value and get value by key.
I haven't much exerience in templates usage, and cannot find a mistake.

[image: Screenshot]

1. Line 1:Error C2663: std::_Tree<_Traits>::find: error C2663: : 2 overloads have no legal;
2. Line 2: Error c2664: std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert(std::pair &&): param 1 from "std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>" в "std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&";

So i have interface:

```
IContainer.h

class ElemNotFound {};
template <class ElemType, class IndexType> 
class IContainer
{
public:
    virtual ~IContainer() {};
    virtual const ElemType& GetElem( const IndexType& index ) const throw ( ElemNotFound ) = 0;
    virtual void PutElem( const IndexType& index, const ElemType& elem ) throw () = 0;
};
```

And

```
Container.h

#include <map>
#include "IContainer.h"

template <class ElemType, class IndexType>
class Container: public IContainer <ElemType, IndexType>
{
private:
    typedef  std::map<ElemType, IndexType> CMap;
    CMap myMap;

public:
    inline const ElemType& GetElem( const IndexType& index ) const throw ( ElemNotFound ) {

        auto  it = myMap.find(index); // line 1

        if (toRet == end()) {
            throw ElemNotFound();
        }

        return toRet->second;
     }

     inline void PutElem( const IndexType& index, const ElemType& elem ) throw () {
         myMap.insert(make_pair(index, elem));  // line 2
     }
};

int main()
{
    Container < string, int> c;
    c.PutElem(1, "as");
    c.PutElem(2, "G");
    c.GetElem(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `map::find` requires a `key_type` (`ElemType` in your case). You are passing it a `IndexType`. Did you mean to write `typedef std::map<IndexType, ElemType> CMap;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetElem` is a `const` method, so you need to get a `const_iterator`, because that is what the [`const` overload of `std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) returns. You also need to use `typename` because `const_iterator` is a dependent name in this context:

```
typename CMap::const_iterator it = myMap.find(index);
```

You can get this automatically by using `auto`:

```
auto it = myMap.find(index);
```

Note that you could simplify that member function to

```
const ElemType& GetElem( const IndexType& index ) const
{
  return myMap.at(index);
}
```

provided it is OK to return an `std::out_of_range` exception. Also note that exception specifications are deprecated.

Besides that, `toRet` is not declared, neither is `end()`, and the type of `myMap` has the key and mapped type the wrong way around. There is a fixed version of your code [**here**](http://ideone.com/reCEgS).

Comment: or simply use `auto` :)

Comment: hm, anyway  error C2663: : 2 overloads have no legal;

Comment: sorry, but auto do not decide my trouble, error anyway (

Comment: @user3780799 You had many errors. Here is [a fixed version of your code](http://ideone.com/reCEgS). The main issue is that the type of your map has the key and element type the wrong way around.